# How to use the PowerShell match operator

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0

**Version: PowerShell 2.0**

I have the following:

```
$pattern = '^.\d_\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d_\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d.pdf$'
$filename = '123456_12345678_12345678901234.pdf'
$filename -match $pattern
```

I want the ^ and $ characters to start and end the string. Since I'm using the wild card '.' in the beginning, I really just care about the $ terminator. These characters do not appear to work as I expect in PowerShell because the above code returns FALSE.

What pattern will return true for $goodname, but false for $badname. The number of digits in the first segment of the name is unknown.

```
$goodname = '123456_12345678_12345678901234.pdf'
$badname = '123456_12345678_12345678901234.pdf.hold'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns false because the `filename` does not match the `pattern`.

A better regex would be:

```
$pattern = '^\d+_\d{8}_\d{14}\.pdf$'
$filename = '123456_12345678_12345678901234.pdf'
$filename -match '\d{6}_\d{8}_\d{14}\.pdf.*'
```

### Explanation

- `^` At the start of the string
- `\d+` Match at least one digit (as you said the number of digits here is unknown)
- `_` Match an underscore
- `\d{8}` Match 8 digits
- `_` Match an underscore
- `\d{14}` Match 14 digits
- `\.` Match a dot `.`
- `pdf` Match "pdf"
- `$` And don't match if you are not now at the end of the string.